# What was the background music in episode 14 of Your Lie In April, starting from 08:52?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

What was the background music in episode 14 of Your Lie In April, starting from 08:52? I can't find it in the OST album. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

The song is called 'Again' - It's Track 26 of Soundtrack CD1, if I recall correctly.

Here is the link to an youtube video of the song, should you need one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKeI8eYtWyQ